# JQuery: prevent events defined in AjaxComplete to be bound (and triggered) multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I run into an issue with the `ajaxComplete()` function of JQuery (latest).
Here's the scenario:
A form is shown in a lightbox to allow users to enter a shipping address.
The submit button for that form is bound to a function in the `ajaxComplete()` section of the script (because the form itself is loaded using Ajax). The form data is sent to the server through Ajax too. If the data entered by the user is incomplete/invalid, error message is displayed and the user can give it another go. Problem is, each time he does, the `.done()` Ajax function is executed multiple times, exponentially: once first time, then twice, then 4 times, etc.
I suppose this is because every time an Ajax call is made and completes (like the form submit), the event is bound a second time, then those 2 events are bound again, making it 4 of them  :-(

Here's a code snippet:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#frm_create_address').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = $('#frm_create_address').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : '/ajax_results.asp?doIT=checkoutCreateAddress',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'text',
            encode      : true
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            alert("Answer: " + data);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("error: " + textStatus);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I'm at loss here... What would be the best way to prevent the multiple triggering of the `.done()` function?

Actually a better questions is: what is the best way to prevent the multiple binding of the submit event :-/

Thanks in advance for your help!
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `global: false` in your ajax function.

> global (default: `true`)
>   Type: **Boolean**
>   Whether to trigger global
>   Ajax event handlers for this request. The default is `true`. Set to
>   `false` to prevent the global handlers like `ajaxStart` or `ajaxStop`
>   from being triggered. This can be used to control various Ajax Events.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplication of the event handlers calls you need to `off` previously setted listener

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
var form = $('#frm_create_address');
form.off('submit', submitListener);
form.on('submit', submitListener);
});

function submitListener(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var formData = $('#frm_create_address').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : '/ajax_results.asp?doIT=checkoutCreateAddress',
    data        : formData,
    dataType    : 'text',
    encode      : true
})

    .done(function(data) {
        alert("Answer: " + data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("error: " + textStatus);
    });

return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi MysterX, thank you for your answer, unfortunately after implementing your suggestion, I got the exact same behaviour on submit. Setting global : false in the Ajax call like naveen suggested did the trick though! Thanks to both of you.